# Find a complete sufficient statistic T for the interior of a triangle

Tags: statistics

This is a textbook problem from a book by Keener.

For $\theta\gt0$, let $\Delta_\theta=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x\gt0,y\gt0,x+y\lt\theta\}$, which is the interior of a triangle. Let $(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_n,Y_n)$ be iid from the uniform distribution on $\Delta_\theta$, so their common density is $\frac 2 {\theta^2}1_{\Delta_\theta}$ (indicator divided by area of triangle). Find a complete sufficient statistic T and the UMVU estimators of $\theta$ and $\cos\theta$.

**Work**:

$f((X_1,Y_1),...,(X_n,Y_n)|\theta)=\displaystyle \prod\frac 2{\theta^2}\textbf 1\{X_i>0\}\textbf 1\{Y_i>0\}\textbf 1\{X_i+Y_i<\theta\}=\frac {2^n}{\theta^{2n}}\textbf 1\{X_{(1)}>0\}\textbf 1\{Y_{(1)}>0\}\textbf 1\{\max\{X_i+Y_i\}<\theta\}=\underbrace{\textbf 1\{X_{(1)}>0\}\textbf 1\{Y_{(1)}>0\}}\underbrace{\frac {2^n}{\theta^{2n}}\textbf 1\{\max\{X_i+Y_i\}<\theta\}}$ so by the factorization theorem $T=\max\{X_i+Y_i\}$ is a sufficient statistic (right?).

Now to show if it's complete, I need to show that $E(f(T))=c$ implies that $f(T)=c$ i.e. is the constant function. And I'm not sure how to do it. $E(f(T))=\displaystyle \int_0^\theta f(x)f_T(x)dx=c$ where $f(x)$ is any function and $f_T(x)$ is the pdf of $T$. What is the pdf of $\max\{X_i+Y_i\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good.

To find the density of $\max(X+Y)$ first derive the distribution of $Z=X+Y$

[image]

$$F_Z(z)=\frac{z^2}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\theta^2}=\frac{z^2}{\theta^2}$$

Thus

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{2 z}{\theta^2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;\theta]}(z)$$

$Z_i$ are independent thus you surely will be able to find the law of $\max(Z_i)$